# How to Scan multiple Hostnames to resolve Ip addresses Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am looking for some help with a script that will read a textfile full of server names and resolve the IP address and export this into a csv file. I am using powershell for this and the Test-Connection command. Please see below code - i am getting the error - cmdlet ForEach-Object at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for the following parameters:Process[0]:

(removed my username and swapped with ***)

```
$array=@()
$computer=Get-Content -Path c:\Users\****\Desktop\ping_IP_host\computers.txt
ForEach ($server in $computer){
if(Test-Connection $server -Quiet)
{
try {
$IP=
[System.net.dns]::GetHostEntry($server).AddressList | %
{$_.IpAddressTostring}
}
catch {"Invalid HostName" - $server}

$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Hostname=$server
    IP=$IP
    }
$array += $obj

else {
$IP="Invalid Host"
}
$obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Hostname=$server
    IP=$IP
    }
$array += $obj
}
}
$array | Export-Csv C:\Users\****\Desktop\ping_IP_host\results.csv
```

Comment: If you indent your code and set the brackets correctly, you will probably find the error. As it is now the `else` block comes before the `if` block finishes and there are too many ending brackets.

Comment: Thanks for indentation reminder - managed to identify error :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a misplace curly bracket, duplicated code, logic error and unwrapped objects.

Indenting properly will help you to find errors and duplicated code.

The custom object you build does contain both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, so you may want to join the 2 addresses OR just select the IPv4 address - I do not know your requirements.

*Edit:*

The `try..catch` block is not needed as it depends on `GetHostEntry()` getting a result for the DNS lookup of `$server`, which is already verified by the `test-connection`. In short, your code defaults to the `else` clause "Invalid Host" when the host does not exist OR the host does not answer to ICMP.
the `try..catch` block around `$IP = ([System.net.dns]::GetHostEntry($server).AddressList`  should be located before the `Test-Connection` because an error means the host name is invalid so no point in trying a ping.

Note: The code below does not take into account the above edit.

Working code:

```
$array=@()
$computer=Get-Content -Path $env:userprofile\Desktop\ping_IP_host\computers.txt
ForEach ($server in $computer) {
    if (Test-Connection $server -Quiet -count 1) {
        try {
            $IP = ([System.net.dns]::GetHostEntry($server).AddressList | ForEach-Object {$_.IPAddressToString} ) -join ";"
        }
        catch {"Invalid HostName" - $server}
    }
    else {
        $IP="Invalid Host"
    }
    $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Hostname = $server
        IP = $IP
    }
    $array += $obj
}

$array | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $env:userprofile\Desktop\ping_IP_host\results.csv
```

Output:

```
"IP","Hostname"
"216.58.206.68;2a00:1450:4002:803::2004","www.google.com"
"Invalid Host","jupiter"
"Invalid host","microsoft.com"
```

Select IPv4 address only

```
$array=@()
$computer=Get-Content -Path $env:userprofile\computers.txt
ForEach ($server in $computer) {
    if (Test-Connection $server -Quiet -count 1) {
        try {
            $IP = [System.net.dns]::GetHostEntry($server).AddressList | Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'} | ForEach-Object {$_.IPAddressToString}
        }
        catch {"Invalid HostName" - $server}
    }
    else {
        $IP="Invalid Host"
    }
    $obj = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Hostname = $server
        IP = $IP
    }
    $array += $obj
}

$array | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation $env:userprofile\Desktop\ping_IP_host\results.csv
```

Output:

```
"IP","Hostname"
"216.58.206.68","www.google.com"
"Invalid Host","jupiter"
"Invalid host","microsoft.com"
```

Comment: Thanks for the above mike and pointing out the errors. I am now able to get the output required. Although when i add in a host that is invalid the catch does not work i get the constant error - Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'TEST' failed: No such host is known At C:\Users\****\Desktop\ping_IP_host\scan_hosts.ps1:6 char:8
+     if(Test-Connection $server){ + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo  : ResourceUnavailable: (DVTEST108:String) [Test-Connection], PingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TestConnectionException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestConnectionCommand

Comment: confirmed, faulty logic, let me edit with an amended version